# How do you bind raw HTML drop down list selection to MVC model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to stack overflow and MVC.

I have a drop down list built dynamically by Jquery from selection of another ddl. The ddl fills but I'm struggling to understand how to bind a selection to the model property for use on the server.

My raw html ddl

```
<select id="projectcode"></select>
```

It is filled with this script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").change(function () {
            if ($("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").val() != "Please select") {
                var options = {};
                options.url = "/IssueView/GetIssueList";
                options.type = "POST";
                options.data = JSON.stringify({ code: $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").val() });
                options.dataType = "json";
                options.contentType = "application/json";
                options.success = function (data) {
                    $("#projectcode").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                        $("#projectcode").append("<option>" + obj.ProjectCode + "</option>");
                    });

                    $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", false);
                };
                options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving codes!"); };
                $.ajax(options);
            }
            else {
                $("#projectcode").empty();
                $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The model property to be assigned to is ProjectNo which is a string. If it was an htmlhelper it would be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectNo, ViewBag.ProjectCodes as SelectList, "Please Select")
```

I've searched but can't find a solution. It's probably something very easy so apologies in advance.

I hope this is complete enough for community requirements.

Thanks for reading - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dynamically creating the elements in javascript/jQuery, then trying to use Razor to tie your Dropdown to the Model is more of a headache than it's worth.

What I always wind up doing is having a singular property on my Model that will be just the selection when the form gets submitted. Then set that to be in a hidden input.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectNo, new { id="projectHidden" }) // There might be other parameters to the signature.
<select id="populatedByJQuery"/>
```

Then down in your javascript, typcially at the bottom of your .cshtml file, you'll need to set up a click event on your submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#projectHidden').val($('#populatedByJQuery').find('option:selected').val());

            $('#form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you already have one of these sections set up in your page, or even in a separate file, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @krillgar. Sorry for the noob questions. I've just tried the suggestion without success. Where would I place the js function? Is it within my script or as its own stand alone script? Thanks again.

Comment: I'll update my answer. If it is still not working, please let me know what it's doing. Obviously, you'll need to change your selectors for your button and form.

Comment: ahh ok, being a noob I was presuming jquery was binding with some sort of generic selector! I guess I can use the button css class as a selector? But not sure how to attach to the form because I am using Html.BeginForm and there is no class to use.

Comment: I would use an ID for the button, cause you don't want multiple items that match the class to trigger form submission. As far as attaching an ID to the Form, there are several overloads on the `Html.BeginForm` method that include an HTML Options object. For example, this method signature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thanks krillgar - managed to get it working. Found how to add an id to the form and button, and works a treat. Thanks for your help - much appreciated.